# Having a really short time to accept a PhD offer

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I got a PhD offer from a good university, and they told me that I should announce my final decision in less than four days. Many other universities have not started interviews yet, and I really want to consider all of my possible options. I do not want to lose this offer, too. The university is also part of the Resolution Regarding Graduate Scholars, Fellows, Trainees, and Assistants.

Comment: which country? which faculty? is it a PhD offer with or without fundings?

Comment: The April 15 resolution is a US and Canada thing, so I am guessing this university is in one of those two countries? It is odd that they would set such a quick deadline if they are part of the resolution.....

Answer (score 1):

You have a trial period for the PhD, as in any job offer.
Read the fine prints of the offer you received. The Resolution you mention states that:

> If a student accepts an offer before April 15 and subsequently desires
> to withdraw that acceptance, the student may submit a written
> resignation of the appointment at any time through April 15.
> Applicants are not required to obtain a formal release from the
> program whose offer they accepted, either before or after the April 15
> deadline. Once applicants have informed the program that they are
> withdrawing their acceptance of the offer, they then can accept any
> other offers

but there are many exception to the Resolution, so I strongly suggest you to contact the admission office of the University to ask if a Phd in (whatever subject is your offer) is covered by the Resolution.

Comment: This is good advice - I find that law schools, medical schools, and some business schools are less likely to follow the resolution, even if the university is a signatory. See here: https://cgsnet.org/april-15-resolution-faq/

Comment: @Dawn Indeed, as explained in your link the resolution is specifically about offers for financial support, and professional degree programs offered by those sorts of schools are much less likely to involve financial support (e.g., via graduate assistantships). OP mentioned a PhD program, though, so that makes it quite a bit more unusual that their program would be exempt from the commitment.

Answer (score 0):

Only giving you four days to respond is unprofessional.  Ask them to extend the deadline.  If they refuse, you should consider declining the offer, assuming you do not have a good reason to think they will stop behaving unprofessionally.